# Android ListView item click and server request

Tags: android

I have a listview and a row of this listview have an image and a like button. When a user presses the like button the image gets liked, and presses the like button again, the image gets disliked. What is the best way to update the like icon (to like and unlike) after getting the response from server. If in case like response takes more then 10 second and in between the user clicks on 30 more likes button after scrolling the listview then how we handle so many requests?

Comment: While you app is requesting and has not received any response from the server then disable the request function, or showing the loading progress at the like button to prevent user to re-click the like button.

Comment: Why wait for a server response to inform the user that they have liked something? What's stopping you from swapping the image to liked and posting the request regardless?

Comment: Do you need server response at click? If thats not a must change the image and make a server request.

Comment: I m not talking about same like button. The user clicks new like button after scrolling the list

Comment: Why would a simple like request take 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing that when you click on like button at that time take object of that particular item from server by calling webservice and replace that with your listitem..

So, that you get perfect view of like and unlike in your listview.

For Ex:

```
list.remove(position1);
list.add(position1,yourbean);
lstAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```